# What does passive されてはねぇ means?

Tags: passive-voice, negation

> 彼に迫る上であなたは利用価値が高い
>
> こんなところで脱落されてはねぇ

"I can't allow you to be desert me"? or is ね particle? Why the passive?

Answer (score 3):

It's a suffering passive construction followed by ては/では.

- 脱落する
  to drop out
- 脱落される
  to *(unfortunately/annoyingly)* drop out
  ([suffering passive](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/50432/5010))
- 脱落されては
  if you drop out
  ([ては for "if", indicates a bad result follows](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AF-%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF-tewa-dewa-meaning/))
- 脱落されてはねぇ
  if you drop out, you know...
  ([ね as an interjectory particle meaning "you know (what I mean)"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/42321/5010))

> 彼に迫る上であなたは利用価値が高い。
> You are valuable in approaching him.
>
> こんなところで脱落されてはねぇ…
> If you drop out at a place like this, you know...

Answer (score 1):

A note on terminology. From the beginning of Japanese linguistics as done by Japanese linguists in the early 20th century, the type of passive called 'suffering passive' here, has been called 間接受身, and thus borrowed into English as 'indirect passive'.

Very frequently though, it was called 'adversative passive' in English and this seems to have been borrowed into Japanese as 被害受身 or 迷惑受身 in the last 20 or so years, so if you are reading material in English you will see 'indirect passive' or 'adversative passive'. It is not unique to Japanese, also being found in Chinese, Korean and Mongolian (amongst others).